# Unable to remove openjdk debian9.6

Tags: java, debian, uninstallation

Linux noob.
I am trying to un-install openjdk but when I attempt it cannot find the package

```
$ java -version

openjdk version "1.8.0_181" 
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_181-8u181-b13-2~deb9u1-b13)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.181-b13, mixed mode)

$ sudo apt remove openjdk+

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package openjdk
```

Comment: Try `whereis java` and remove the corresponding folder where jdk is located.

Comment: @Gunasekar, that's the worst idea.

Comment: uninstall using sudo apt-get remove. purge using sudo apt-get purge. Check this link for more information https://www.howtoinstall.co/en/debian/stretch/openjdk-8-jdk?action=remove

Answer (score 1):

To uninstall OpenJDK you should use `APT` with the command

```
$ sudo apt-get remove openjdk-*
```

the `*` wildcard will match whatever version of `OpenJDK` you have installed